# Casting error when I'm not trying to cast anything

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a simple card game to work ... and I'm getting an "Impossible to cast " error ... but I'm not trying to cast anything ... I'm a little confuse about why I get this error. Heres a quick summary of the 3 object I use.

```
Public Class Holder
  inherits Panel
end class

Public Class Card
   inherits PictureBox
end class

public Class Location
 Public Property X as integer
 Public Property Y as integer
end class

Public Class Board
   inherits Form

  Public Property Tile as Dictionnary(of Location, Holder)

  Public sub PlayCard(card as Card, loc as Location)
   Tile(loc).Controls.Add(card)
  end sub

end Class
```

and I get an InvalidCastException:

Impossible to cast objet type 'Holder' in Type 'Card'.

I've triple check to make sure its really a card thats being pass as a parameter to the PlayCard sub .... and I get no idea what to do from here ...

any suggestions ?

EDIT :

```
 Private Sub TEST() Handles Board.Load
   Dim c = New Card
   Dim p1 As Location
   p1 = New Location(2, 1)

   c.Image = My.Resources.Tree

   Me.Play(c, p1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code where you get the exception, what are you trying to pass to `PlayCard` as `Card`? Btw what is an `ImpossibleCastException`?

Comment: Nothing on MSDN for ImpossibleCastException

Comment: ... InvalidCast ... my bad... I get the exception on the Tile(loc).Controls.Add(card)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haaaaaaaaaaaaaaa I find it  ... a friend of mine told me to watch out for events and he was right.

I'm using an event that Handles Holder.ControlAdded

The sender of that even is the Holder itself, I had assume it was the control added, hence the InvalidCastError.

the error get raised on the control.add() line instead of inside the event, which leads to my confusion.